# How to reconstruct NSAttributedString from JSON data

Tags: objective-c, json, nsattributedstring, nsjsonserialization

I have this `NSAttributedString` object that I have managed to write in a file like this:

```
{
  "string" : "Hello World",
  "runs" : [
    {
      "range" : [0,3],
      "attributes" : {
        "font" : {
          "name" : "Arial",
          "size" : 12
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "range" : [3,6],
      "attributes" : {
        "font" : {
          "name" : "Arial",
          "size" : 12
        },
        "color" : [255,0,0]
      }
    },
    {
      "range" : [9,2],
      "attributes" : {
        "font" : {
          "name" : "Arial",
          "size" : 12
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I have to read the data back and reconstruct the `NSAttributedString`
any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deserialize your JSON string to get a dictionary with values. Then parse out the bits as you need them.

First parse out the string:

```
NSString *myString = [dictionaryFromJson objectForKey:@"string"];
NSMutableAttributedString *myAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:myString];
```

Then parse out the array:

```
NSArray *attributes = [dictionaryFromJson objectForKey:@"runs"];
```

Then traverse the array and for each dictionary in it, create the attributes as needed:

```
for(NSDictionary *dict in attributes)
{
    NSArray *rangeArray = [dict objectForKey:@"range"];
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange([(NSNumber*)[rangeArray objectAtIndex:0] intValue], [(NSNumber*)[rangeArray objectAtIndex:0] intValue]); //you may need to make sure here your types in array match up and of course that you are in bounds of array

    NSDictionary *attributesDictionary = [dict objectForKey:@"attributes"];

    //I'll do the font as example
    NSDictionary *fontDictionary = [attributesDictionary objectForKey:@"font"];
    if(fontDictionary)
    {
        NSString *fontName = [fontDictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
        float fontSize = [[fontDictionary objectForKey:@"size"] floatValue];
        UIFont *myFont = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize];

        if(myFont)
        {
             [myAttributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:myFont range:range];
        }
    }
}
```

Then just carry on with the rest of the values, manipulating data based on whether they come from dictionaries or arrays.

You will also need to do some validation, null-checks etc., so this code is by no means complete.

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply, I do have a couple of followup questions though, as in the example JSON, the attributed string has more than one "range" item. So when I try to do it your way, I only get the first range... but there can be more ranges since different parts of the string can have different attributes

Comment: The line for(NSDictionary *dict in attributes) will pull out each dictionary one at a time. Your original JSON string only has one range per each set of attributes. So you pull out that range and that set of attributes and create them for that specific range. I only did the font, but you'd then do the color and any other attribute in the same way. Then the next time you'd go in the loop it would pull out another dictionary with a single value for range and a j array of values for attributes.

Comment: Shouldn't the argument for `addAttribute`: should be `NSFontAttributeName` and argument for `value` be `myFont`?

Comment: You are right, UIFont is for iOS and NSFont is for Mac OS X. The second part you are also correct - edited the code to reflect that.

Comment: I am using the code as you have suggested, but somehow it doesnt seem to work. After the execution of the line: `[myAttributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:myFont range:range];` the attributes are still empty, although there is no error

Comment: How are you checking the attributes?

Comment: in debug mode, I just print the description out in log :Printing description of myAttributedString:
`onary *attri{
}`

Comment: oh, I dont know how, but it is working fine now! 
just final question :D : My strings from JSON are all backslash escaped, is there an easy way to remove the escaping?

Comment: when you perform deserializing that should take care of the slashes. how are you converting from JSON to dictionary?